How to fill a subfield based on conditions in Matlab
For each of 20 trials, I have a structure S, with 50 subfields. One of these subfields, type, is a 1x50000 structure with 50 fields. I need to add a field condition to the subfield structure 'type', to have S.type.condition.
[S.type.condition] = deal(''); %adds the subfield to S.type
This new subfields needs to be populated based on two of the existing subfields: S.type.pres (with values from 1 to 2) and S.type.stimulus (with values from 1 to 3), such that if
`S.type.stimulus == 1 & S.type.pres == 1` then `S.type.condition ==1`
`S.type.stimulus == 2 & S.type.pres == 1` then `S.type.condition ==2`
`S.type.stimulus == 3 & S.type.pres == 1` then `S.type.condition ==3`
`S.type.stimulus == 1 & S.type.pres == 2` then `S.type.condition ==4`
`S.type.stimulus == 2 & S.type.pres == 2` then `S.type.condition ==5`
`S.type.stimulus == 3 & S.type.pres == 2` then `S.type.condition ==6`

I need to repeat this for each of the 20 trials.

You’re computing condition = (pres-1)*3 + stimulus. Just write a loop to set those values.

It works, many thanks!
